# Running a query to analyse sales data in SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to write a query that will show if a sale has been registered to a different working date.

So for example; I have my `TransactionHistory` table and inside it are `WorkingDay` and `DateOfSale`.

I believe some sales have been placed through on a `DateOfSale` between 2013-10-21 and 2013-10-25 but have been registered to a different working day.

The query I am trying to run looks like this:

```
select WorkingDate, DateOfSale 
from transactionhistory 
where WorkingDate < DateOfSale
```

This is fine but I want to factor the date range in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really simple, you just need to add an extra condition to your WHERE clause:

```
SELECT WorkingDate, DateOfSale 
FROM transactionhistory 
WHERE DateOfSale BETWEEN '2013-10-21'
     AND '2013-10-25' AND WorkingDate < DateOfSale
```

That will pick up any entries from your `transactionhistory` table that has a `DateOfSale` between your two dates and where the `WorkingDate` is before the `DateOfSale`.